# Subclass of dataclass, with some assertions

Tags: python

I have a frozen dataclass `MyData` that holds data.
I would like a distinguished subclass `MySpecialData` can only hold data of length 1.
Here is a working implementation.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyData:
    id: int = field()
    data: list[float] = field()

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.data)


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MySpecialData(MyData):
    def __post_init__(self):
        assert len(self) == 1


# correctly throws exception
special_data = MySpecialData(id=1, data=[2, 3])
```

I spent some time messing with `__new__` and `__init__`, but couldn't reach a working solution.
The code works, but I am a novice and am soliciting the opinion of someone experienced if this is the "right" way to accomplish this.
Any critiques or suggestions on how to do this better or more correctly would be appreciated.

For examples not using `dataclasses`, I imagine the correct way would be overriding `__new__` in the subclass.
I suspect my attempts at overriding `__new__` fail here because of the special way `dataclasses` works.
Would you agree?

Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `assert`. Use

```
if len(self) != 1:
    raise ValueError
```

`assert` can be turned off with the `-O` switch ie., if you run your script like

```
python -O my_script.py
```

it will no longer raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a custom user-defined `list` subclass, which checks the `len` of the list upon instantiation.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Sequence, TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')


class ConstrainedList(list, Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, seq: Sequence[T] = (), desired_len: int = 1):
        super().__init__(seq)

        if len(self) != desired_len:
            raise ValueError(f'expected length {desired_len}, got {len(self)}. items={self}')


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyData:
    id: int = field()
    data: ConstrainedList[float] = field(default_factory=ConstrainedList)


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MySpecialData(MyData):
    ...


# correctly throws exception
special_data = MySpecialData(id=1, data=ConstrainedList([2, 3]))
```